# Looking for a font where 0, 1, 2, 5, and 8 are the same when flipped upside down

Tags: fonts

For example, the number 10258 should read 85201 when flipped upside down.  This is akin to what would happen with these digits on a 7-segment LED display (although strictly speaking the 1 would switch sides when flipped upside down).  I'd prefer if it weren't literally a replica of a 7-segment display and instead looked more like a traditional (probably sans serif) font.

To clarify in response to some of the questions given in response, I'm looking for a font that depicts the digits 0 through 9 as traditional Arabic numerals.  The goal is that if you take the depiction of the digits 0, 1, 2, 5, or 8 and rotate it 180 degrees you get an image identical to the original digit before rotation.  The digits 1 would presumably be a simple vertical line, the 0 a generally elliptical shape with 180 degree rotational symmetry, and so on.  In many fonts the upper and lower halves of an 8 are often slightly different in size or shape and here you'd want a font that depicts the 8's upper and lower halves the same when rotated 180 degrees.  The greatest variance from traditional fonts would be for the 2 and 5, which are normally not rotationally symmetric whereas I'd like something similar to an S shape for the 5 and the same, mirrored, for the 2.

Comment: Can you please explain more what do you mean by flip upside down?

Comment: @Vikas - Google "calculator boobs" for a simple, if puerile, explanation ;)

Comment: Just added clarifications to the question.  But, in short, comment about calculator BOOBS (= 58008 upside down) is basically correct.  I could manually create the digits from scratch, but it would be nice if there was a font that already did this, so that I could use other characters in that font and have them all share a visual consistency.  I'm also sensitive to wanting the invertible digits to look "normal"; for example, sticking two copies of a circle on top of each other gives an 8, but not in the natural looking way that good font designers achieve.

Comment: @Vikas makes a good point: rotate 180° as with a calculator, or mirror? The latter is what springs to  mind when you say "flip", but the mention of the 1 switching sides suggests rotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend hiring someone on Upwork to make this font for you; a 10-character font shouldn't take long and shouldn't be very expensive. Plus that way you could get full rights to the font to do whatever you want with it and have it in exactly the weight, width etc. you want.

The problem is that you're not going to find a font like this easily. Well-designed fonts are generally asymmetric; the top of the 8 is generally slightly smaller than the bottom. No normal font would have a '5' and '2' like you describe; no normal font designer would make the digits that way.

Comment: This is for a puzzle and I ultimately just need the digits 0-9.  Central to the puzzle is that rotating some of the pieces 180 degrees gives you the same number.  In other words it's low enough stakes that I'll probably just make up something akin to 7-digit display digits rather than seek out a full fledged font.  But I'm hoping that there's some idiosyncratic font out there that might give me what I need and look better than what I'd come up with.   That is, if there is one and I can find it given how many fonts are out there.

Comment: Te 8 would be far less of an issue than the 2 and 5. In fact the 8 in this comment box, when mirrored vertically, matches the apart from effects of antialiasing.  The 2 and 5 wouldn't even look much like 2 and 5

Comment: @ChrisH have you understood the problem? If yes, can you please help let me understand?

Comment: @Vikas I think the OP needs to clarify - IMO the question is inconsistent

Comment: You can find an example of what I want at https://ibb.co/Xz057Zz.  I created these myself earlier today since my original posting seems to be confusing to some  readers.  Note that if you turn it upside down the digits 0, 1, 2, 5, and 8 are unchanged.  I'm hoping there's a font that does the same thing for these digits but looks more polished than my amateur effort.